# Passing multiple arguments on Cucumber step definition

Tags: java, regex, automation, cucumber

I have cucumber step like this

```
Given I am on (Similar Article Alerts|Search Alerts|Journal Alerts) page
```

I have a step definition for this

```
  @Given("^I am on \"([^\"]*)\" page$")
   public void iAmOnSimilar_X_Page(String pageName) throws Throwable {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
   }
```

but I am getting Undefined step reference. 
Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: You do not have quotes there, right? Try `@Given("^I am on \((.*)\) page$")` if the text you need to pass as `pageName` is between parentheses. Remove `\(` and `\)` if there can be just any text between `on` and `page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to escape the opening and closing parenthesis `\(` and `\)` instead of double quotes, they are not present in your example data.

In the negating character class match not a closing parenthesis `[^)]+`

[`^I am on \(([^)]*)\) page$`](https://regex101.com/r/wU82gr/1)

In Java:

```
String regex = "^I am on \\(([^)]*)\\) page$";
```